# CPU heating too much, cpufrequtils to limit its speed works weird

Tags: linux, cpu, linux-mint, cpu-speed, cpufreq

I am using an Intel i5 powered laptop and my OS is a 64 bit Linux Mint 14, kernel version 3.5.0-43.

Up until now the CPU usage policy was `ondemand` and it usually was working at 2.40Ghz. In this setup it kept overheating and shutting down.

I installed `cpufrequtils` and changed using `cpufreq-set` the maximum frequency to 2.0 Ghz and switched the policy to `conservative`.

What I find weird is that these changes appear to have been committed only in the case of CPU 0, the other 3 cores (the CPU has 2 physical cores HyperThreading enabled) appear to be running in the same configuration as before, as reported by `cpufreq-info`.

Am I reading the results badly ? If not, what can I do about it. I want all the cores to run in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use the `-c` flag and use 0,1,2,3 to point to a certain CPU, or use the `-r` flag which means to apply the setting to all the hardware-related CPUs.